# button cannot trigger in mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I am having some trouble in ASP.NET MVC4 - When I click the Login button it's not hitting my controller and not logging in

This is the code on my .cshtml

```
@using System.Linq
```

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Login", FormMethod.Post, new { @Class = "form-signin", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Login failed. Check your login details.")
            <img class="img-responsive" src="~/Images/PI%20Logo.jpg" />
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.userName, new {@Class = "form-control", @Id = "user", @placeholder = "Username"})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.userName)
            @Html.PasswordFor(p => p.passwd, new {@Class = "form-control", @Id = "pass", @placeholder = "Password"})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.passwd)
            <!--<input class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Username" type="text" />
            <input class="form-control" id="Password1" placeholder="Password" type="password" /> -->
            <input id="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="button" value="LOGIN" />
        }
    </div>

    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

and this is my controller

```
public class LoginController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Login/

    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(Login login)
    {
        AccountManagement am = new AccountManagement();
        var xrm = new XrmServiceContext("Xrm");

        SystemUser sysUser = xrm.SystemUserSet.Where(x => x.DomainName == "hc\\" + login.userName && x.IsDisabled == false).FirstOrDefault();

        if (am.ValidateCredentials(login.userName, login.passwd) == "True" && sysUser != null)
        {
            Session["username"] = login.userName;
            return RedirectToAction("MainHome", "MainMenu");//Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new { Message = "Success", User = sysUser });
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Login data is incorrect!");//Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "Username or Password Invalid");
        }
        return View(login);
    }

}
```

What's wrong with my code - i'm so confused, because many tutorial made simple login like this but it's work

Comment: If you want to submit the form it should be `<input type="submit" ..>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change button type to submit

```
<input id="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" value="LOGIN" />
```

Difference between input type Button & submit

```
<input type="button" />
```

buttons will not submit a form - they don't do anything by default. They're generally used in conjunction with JavaScript as part of an AJAX application.

```
<input type="submit">
```

buttons will submit the form they are in when the user clicks on them, unless you specify otherwise with JavaScript.

Comment: Nice - fast  answer ;) - want to explain why it wasn't working for them ?